# Finding polynomal function with given zeros and one zero is a square root

Tags: polynomials, roots

I've been having trouble with this problem: Find a polynomial function of minimum degree with $-1$ and $1-\sqrt{3}$ as zeros. Function must have integer coefficients.

When I tried it, I got this:

\begin{align}
(x+1)(x-(1-\sqrt{3}))=& x^2 - x(1-\sqrt{3}) + x - 1 + \sqrt{3}\\
    =& x^2 - x + x(\sqrt{3}) + x - 1 + \sqrt{3}\\
    =& x^2 + x(\sqrt{3}) - 1 + \sqrt{3}
\end{align}

This looks completely wrong to me and it probably is as my teacher said the answer should not be a quadratic. I'm not looking for the answer to be given to me; but if I could get some guidance, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A polynomial with 2 roots is *always* quadratic. That's a consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra. So your answer is correct.

Comment: Imagine a linear relation in the cartesian plan. It is a line with some offset and a given steepness. If you extend it to infinity in both direction, you will only cross the $y=0$ axis once, hence there is only one root. Now, if you have a degree 2 polynomial (i.e. 'quadratic' polynomial), then it will be bell shaped (more precisely: parabola). Such a curve *can* cross the axis twice, no matter if it is upward or downward oriented. Polynomial functions of higher order will cross the line more often.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted my teacher when he said it wasn't a quadratic? Thanks for replying!

Comment: @JGab This polynomial doesn't have integer coefficients, so it's not the desired polynomial.

Comment: Oops! I missed that bit :*/ Many excuses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polynomial does not work because it does not have integer coefficients. So no quadratic will work, because the two roots are forced to be $-1$ and $1-\sqrt 3$, and you just showed this doesn't work.

However, a cubic will work. Try the one with $-1$, $1-\sqrt 3$, and $1+\sqrt 3$ as roots.

Comment: I got x^3 - x^2 - 4x - 2 when I use those three as roots. Doesn't look right again :(

Comment: @yayu that agrees with what I got. See my answer.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a polynomial that has those two roots *and* integer coefficients, you'll need to add another root.

Substitute $w = x-1$ so that $(x+1)(x-(1-\sqrt{3})) = (w+2)(w+\sqrt{3})$.

Now multiply by $(w-\sqrt{3})$ to get

$(w+2)(w+\sqrt{3})(w-\sqrt{3}) = (w+2)(w^2-3)$.

Then substitute back in $x$ and you have your polynomial, which is a cubic with integer coefficients:

$(x+1)(x^2-2x-2) = x^3 -2x^2 - 2x + x^2 - 2x - 2 = x^3 - x^2 - 4x - 2$.

Comment: How do you get (w+2)? Where does the 2 come from?
Nevermind, I see it.

Comment: I did the substitution $w = x - 1$ so that the difference of two squares multiplication was clear.  (The one that got rid of the square root.)  Regarding your question:  I replaced $x+1$ with $(w+1)+1$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Never knew you could substitute like this.

Comment: Just one way to do it.  I couldn't wrap my head around what Potato saw by inspection, but I could see that I could get rid of the square root by difference of two squares.  Lots of tricks. :)